# How to rewrite your code in OOP using Pyspark

Tags: python, class, oop, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have a simple dataframe

```py
sdf0 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("eng", "BlackBerry sells legacy patents of mobile devices"),
        ("eng", "Amazon to shut down publishing house Westland Books"),
    ],
    ["lang", "title"],
)
```

| lang | title |
| --- | --- |
| eng | BlackBerry sells legacy patents of mobile devices |
| eng | Amazon to shut down publishing house Westland Books |

I also have a code that extracts filtered words from text

```py
# to lower
sdf = sdf0.withColumn("low_title", F.lower(F.col("title")))

# tokenize
tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="low_title", outputCol="tokens")
sdf1 = tokenizer.transform(sdf)

# filter stopwords
import stopwordsiso

available_lang = {"eng": "en"}
stopwords_iso = {}
for lang in available_langs:
    stopwords_iso[lang] = stopwordsiso.stopwords(available_langs[lang])
stopwords = {k: list(v) for k, v in stopwords_iso.items()}
sdf_filtered = reduce(
    lambda a, b: a.unionAll(b),
    (
        StopWordsRemover(
            inputCol="tokens", outputCol="filtered_words", stopWords=value
        ).transform(sdf1.where(F.col("lang") == key))
        for key, value in stopwords.items()
    ),
)

# explode
sdf_exp = (
    sdf_filtered.withColumn("filtered_word", F.explode("filtered_words"))
    .select("lang", "filtered_word")
    .withColumn(
        "filtered_word",
        F.regexp_replace(
            "filtered_word", r'[!"«»#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~–—0-9]', ""
        ),
    )
    .filter(F.length(F.col("filtered_word")) > 0)
)
```

Output:

```
+----+-------------+
|lang|filtered_word|
+----+-------------+
| eng|   blackberry|
| eng|        sells|
| eng|       legacy|
| eng|      patents|
| eng|       mobile|
| eng|      devices|
| eng|       amazon|
| eng|         shut|
| eng|   publishing|
| eng|        house|
| eng|     westland|
| eng|        books|
+----+-------------+
```

I tried to rewrite it in a class, but I keep getting an error that the columns does not exist. How do I bind previous data frames and feed them into functions? Or is there a simpler way to not write a lot of functions. Thank you.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import stopwordsiso


class Filter_words:
    def __init__(self, sdf):
        self.sdf = sdf

    def lower(self):
        self.sdf = self.sdf.withColumn("low_title", F.lower(F.col("title")))

    def tokenize(self):
        tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="low_title", outputCol="tokens")
        self.sdf = tokenizer.transform(sdf)

    def stop_words(self):
        available_lang = {"eng": "en"}
        stopwords_iso = {}
        for lang in available_langs:
            stopwords_iso[lang] = stopwordsiso.stopwords(available_langs[lang])
        stopwords = {k: list(v) for k, v in stopwords_iso.items()}
        self.sdf = reduce(
            lambda a, b: a.unionAll(b),
            (
                StopWordsRemover(
                    inputCol="tokens", outputCol="filtered_words", stopWords=value
                ).transform(sdf.where(F.col("lang") == key))
                for key, value in stopwords.items()
            ),
        )

    def explode_column(self):
        self.sdf = (
            self.sdf.withColumn("filtered_word", F.explode("tokens"))
            .select("lang", "filtered_word")
            .withColumn(
                "filtered_word",
                F.regexp_replace(
                    "filtered_word", r'[!"«»#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~–—0-9]', ""
                ),
            )
            .filter(F.length(F.col("filtered_word")) > 0)
        )


sdf = Filter_words(sdf0)
```

Comment: where is exactly the error ? what method creates the problem ? Technically, your code should work. We need a bit more of debugging/logging to help you.

Comment: When I call the stop_words function, it says that the column 'tokens' does not exist, and so with the function explode_column too. In the pyspark, I could simply call the previous dataframes, but I don’t understand how to transfer columns here in class

Comment: OK. And after you did `sdf.tokenize()`, what is the output of `sdf.sdf`? do you see the column `tokens` in the dataframe ?

Comment: Yes, I see a column of tokens when I call the function sdf.tokenize(), and therefore I don't understand why other functions don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it - you have at least 3 errors in your code. Use an IDE on a new session, you'll see all the errors

---

1. `tokenize`

```py
    def tokenize(self):
        tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="low_title", outputCol="tokens")
        self.sdf = tokenizer.transform(sdf)

# should be 

    def tokenize(self):
        tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="low_title", outputCol="tokens")
        self.sdf = tokenizer.transform(self.sdf) # self missing
```

2. `stop_words`

```py
    def stop_words(self):
        available_lang = {"eng": "en"}
        stopwords_iso = {}
        for lang in available_langs:
            stopwords_iso[lang] = stopwordsiso.stopwords(available_langs[lang])
        stopwords = {k: list(v) for k, v in stopwords_iso.items()}
        self.sdf = reduce(
            lambda a, b: a.unionAll(b),
            (
                StopWordsRemover(
                    inputCol="tokens", outputCol="filtered_words", stopWords=value
                ).transform(sdf.where(F.col("lang") == key))
                for key, value in stopwords.items()
            ),
        )

# should be 

    def stop_words(self):
        available_langs = {"eng": "en"} # final -s missing
        stopwords_iso = {}
        for lang in available_langs:
            stopwords_iso[lang] = stopwordsiso.stopwords(available_langs[lang])
        stopwords = {k: list(v) for k, v in stopwords_iso.items()}
        self.sdf = reduce(
            lambda a, b: a.unionAll(b),
            (
                StopWordsRemover(
                    inputCol="tokens", outputCol="filtered_words", stopWords=value
                ).transform(self.sdf.where(F.col("lang") == key))  # self missing
                for key, value in stopwords.items()
            ),
        )
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't see the columns 'tokens' again,  if I call the functions

Comment: @Rory Did you do what I asked ? You start a new python - from scratch - no other code than the  OOP part. And you execute it. And then, you tell me the output of `sdf.sdf` after `sdf.tokenize()`. That's just basic debugging. There is not reason that it does not work

Comment: Yes:( I do this 
`sdf_ex = Filter_words(sdf0) 
sdf_ex.tokenize()`

My error:  `low_title does not exist. Available: lang, title`

Comment: @rory because you forgot to apply `sdf.lower()` first.

Comment: @rory I'd advice you to return `self` at the end of each method so you can do `Filter_words(sdf0).lower().tokenize().stop_words().explode_column()` - chaining your methods.